# need to configure sphinx with lumen 5.2

Tags: sphinx, lumen

I have tried to configure the sphinxsearch with the lumen 5.2, but I can not complete that.

```
1) We can not add directly publish the provider in the lumen
2) How to define that provider and alise for the installation.
```

I have used this Sphinx search :- https://github.com/sngrl/sphinxsearch

can anyone help me to integrate this ?

thanks in advance.